# Некорректные данные в отображении репы в чате

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, репутация, чат

Сегодня общался в [чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93292/discussion-between-woesss-and-andrew-goroshko), и увидел проблему:

> [image: репутация в чате]

В чем проблема спросите вы?)) Проблема в том, что у меня репа - 3628 баллов. Мне, конечно, приятно, что система желает мне побольше баллов и т.д., но это мне кажется не очень правильно. Можно как-то исправить :)

Comment: В чате отображается суммарная репутация по [всем сайтам сети](https://stackexchange.com/users/current/?tab=accounts), где репутация >= 200.

Comment: я понял, @αλεχολυτ, может вопрос удалить или пусть будет? по-факту проблемы нет

Comment: Оставляйте для потомства. Вообще это интересный и неочевидный сразу момент.

Comment: ну раз для потомства, то оставлю ;)

Comment: Эх ... @Qwertiy ... Qwertiy-ч

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, ну бывает, не заметил))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чат - общий для всей сети SE. В нем отображается сумма репутации по всем аккаунтам SE. У вас есть аккаунт на английском SO с 300 репутации, он и добавляет разницу.

Comment: что-то странно это все))) логику я не очень понял)) но насколько я понял все нормально работает?

Comment: По всем, да не по всем. Только по тем, где более 200 реп, имхо.

Comment: А ещё чаты немного поделены, отдельно MSE, большой SO и всё остальное. Хотя на суммарную репу это разделение не влияет.